# Login a Windows 7 user on a remote computer on so I can Remote Desktop

Tags: powershell, windows-7, vpn, remote-desktop

I need a way to always make a Windows 7 Pro machine, which will not normally be connected to a keyboard or monitor, ready for Remote Desktop Connection (That is get past the windows user login screen).

Right now I can successfully connect Remotely once, then when I disconnect it is stuck in a user login screen wanting a password. I cannot figure out how to get past that remotely.

I have LogMEIn Hamachi VPN. I am accessing with a laptop with Windows 7 Home Premium using win Remote Desktop Connection.

I am guessing I need a powershell command I can run from the remote laptop computer to log the local computer in... but I know very little scripting or other stuff like that.

I tried removing the password all-together from the machine-to-be-remotely-accessed but that didn't work and, besides, I'd prefer to keep some level of security.

(FYI - it is my giant gaming rig with all my stuff on it, but I am traveling over seas for a few months and a friend offered to keep it in a corner plugged in with internet... so I am trying (with little effect) make it useful to me while I am gone: to maintain access to it for important records, and also use as a proxy so I can still access USA IP address while I am in more restrictive countries)

Comment: Additional Information: You need to have a password set for the user you want to access, or remote will not work.
Also, I am pretty sure that remote desktop is a feature that is only included in at least the Professional version of Windows, are you sure about the Home Edition?

Answer (score 3):

If Remote Desktop is properly configured on the target PC and the firewall allows RD through, you don't need to have a user logged on.
The RD client will ask you for the password of the user you're trying to long on as, but that's to be expected. Is there a reason for wanting to bypass the password?
 I would strongly advise against that, security-wise...

Comment: I can Remote in, the problem is that when I disconnect the computer remoted into is left in the windows log in screen... unable to log in, and my VPN is disconnected since it is a system tray client -- But I just discovered that Hamachi disabled the run as a service feature... thus so you have to pay to get that enabled... I may just do that since workaround seem insecure and unreliable.

Answer (score 0):

I have some knowledge of both PowerShell and of Remote Desktop.  My advice is forget about using PowerShell to fix your problem.

Indeed, I am wondering if there is a problem at all.

Remote machine sits there with nobody logged on - Good because only one user can use that machine at a time.

Remote desktop connects the first time - good.  In my setup, I can remote desktop again for a 2nd or 3rd time.  The target machine just sits there with nobody logged on.

Correct me if I have misunderstood the problem, but if you managed to logon someone on the target machine, they would have to logoff before you could use it remotely.

If you REALLY want an account to logon at the target machine in these circumstances I would configure AutoAdminLogon.  Then just before you finish your remote session tell the machine to reboot - crude but effective.  I use shutdown /I to achieve this.  (I use this AutoAdminLogon technique on a second machine on my network).